# No route matches using rspec on a get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What am I forgetting?

routes:

```
  get "/comingsoon" => "visitors#comingsoon"
  resources :visitors
```

controller:

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
  def comingsoon
    @new_visitor = Visitor.new
  end
end
```

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe VisitorsController do
  describe "GET /comingsoon" do
    it "should be happy" do
      get "/comingsoon"
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the result:

```
✗ rspec spec/controllers/visitors_controller_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) VisitorsController GET /comingsoon should be valid
     Failure/Error: get "/comingsoon"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"visitors", :action=>"/comingsoon"}
     # ./spec/controllers/visitors_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.14226 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/visitors_controller_spec.rb:6 # VisitorsController GET /comingsoon should be valid
```

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your spec file replace `get "/comingsoon"`
 with `get "comingsoon"`

When you spec a controller with rspec the operand of the http verb (get, post, put, delete) is an action of the controller rather than a url.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly daft suggestion, but you have a view right? Otherwise you have to tell your controller to render something.